Can I refill a down sleeping bag myself?
Has anyone refilled his own sleeping bag?
Mine has a few cold spots. I tried washing it again, drying it with tennis balls,... Not as good as I would want. I don't want to throw it away. In my country, I can't get a separate down fill. I am thinking about destroying the down pillow and using it. The problem is that the pillows have whole feathers and are heavier. I don't think that would help a lot in a sleeping bag. I like to keep it ultralight. Has someone done it?
What if I took a few hours and separated the feathers from the stem? Would that work? I can get special repair tape for textiles; it should be strong and cover a few sections, where I will fill the down.

I've not refilled a bag myself, but wouldn't it be better to unstitch the pockets and fill, then restitch rather than rely on tape? Feathers != down, but are often a component of the fill (e.g. in 90/10 fill = 90% is down, 10% is feathers).

So high down ratio means that most of feathers - stems were removed and mostly the fluffy part remains(used for filling)?

@AlexJ. No, Down is a special type of feather with little shaft and lots of fluff, it is not just feathers with the shaft removed. The fluff is not stiff at all, like the barb/vane on feathers. The ratio means that they used 90% down feathers and 10% other feathers; these will be small body feathers not wing or tail feathers

We bought sleeping bags ca 1975 from the North Face.   We used them an average  40 days per year for 40 years.  They are still usable, loosely reclining on a shelf  in a closet.  MY POINT:  Buy a first-class sleeping bag, treat it well and it will be cheaper in the long run than a time-consuming (and probably klugey) do-it-yourself fix on a bag in poor condition.   Dry clean it occasionally, store it loose and away from UV, make an effort to keep it dry when in use, and you will have to buy only two more bags in your life, assuming you are now about 25 and will be camping for another 50 years.

Googling ‘down sleeping bag refill’ pulls up down suppliers, lots of sites to read, and YouTube videos.

The feathers from my down pillow tend to poke out after being "tampered with" and then [slightly] poke me in the face. I guess chopping the pointy parts(+parts of the feather, idk) will yield reliable and comfortable results.
